# Rendering files in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, web-services

I am sending a post request to a rest service to get a content.
The content can be any of the types. (pdf, doc, pptx, docx, img, png, mp3, etc)

I have a very simple html and javascript to load the the content.

html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
click
</head>
<body>
<button type="submit" target='_blank' onclick="Test()">Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function Test() {
    console.log("started");
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               console.log(this.response);
               var bytes = new Uint8Array(this.response); // pass byte response to this constructor

var blob=new Blob([bytes], { type: "*/*"});// change resultByte to bytes

var link=document.createElement('a');
link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.click();
         }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/testService", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");
    xhttp.send("{ \"Id\": \"12345678\" }");
}
```

Now for the line

```
var blob=new Blob([bytes], { type: "*/*"});
```

How do I know what type of file it is.... it wont let me stream it to the browser if I just leave it like `*/*` it needs to be a specific type.

Comment: Do you develop the rest service by yourself? It would be better to send a response header with the apropriate content type, that you can then evaluate with JavaScript. Another way could be sending back a JSON object containing content type and binary data as two different parameters. But far away from that point, it is not possible to render a pdf file in all major browser versions out there. Are you sure you want to render instead of providing a download?

Comment: yes I did wrote the service. The service is returning the following mime type depends on the file content. `headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(fileType));` for this case it would return : `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation` for id 12345678. But i am not sure how to get it when i load it from javascript.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated out in the comments you need to get the content type header, you 've set for the response. Here 's a simple response, which shows how to get the content type header.

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener('load', requestHandler);
xhr.open('GET', your_service_url_here);
xhr.send();

function requestHandler()
{
    console.log(this.getResponseHeader('content-type'));
}
```

More about the `XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader()` method you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getResponseHeader).

For streaming reasons you can use so called data URIs.

```
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,//5mAG8AbwAgAGIAYQByAAoA">text file</a>
```

The [caniuse.com entry](https://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri) for data URIs states out, that the support for data URIs is widely spread. To force an automatically download stream you can execute a click event on a dynamically generated data URI link.

Comment: but this would not stream the content of the document. I would still get blob in the browser

Comment: First you wanted to render a specific file. Now you want to stream. As I said before, rendering won 't be easy without third party libs through cross browser issues. Forcing a download streeam is easy with a data URI. I 've edited my answer above.